# Mediawiki/wikipedia text format issue

Tags: text, format, mediawiki, wikipedia

so i got an issue with text formatting and i have no idea how this problem is called or what i should search after, so i thought i try to explain it here.

It's literally nothing dramatic or should take long, i simply want to write stuff like

```
''italic'' or '''bold'''
```

without that it actually gets italic or bold... i literally want

```
''italic''
```

to be displayed. I've also tried to use code blocks but even within the blocks it writes italic then.. i'm sure there is a <..> command but i simply can not find it

Does anyone know?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about wiki formatting, not programming.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<nowiki>''italic''</nowiki>
```

Comment: Answering non-programming questions encourages posters to ask off-topic questions on the site. In this situation, please refrain from answering, even if you know the answer. Upvoting the question also does not go in the right direction.

Comment: thanks to whoever chose to downvote my answer. grml. at least I earned a hat :-)